# match pattern and replace with count in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

How would I go about getting a count of a pattern match then replace the pattern with the count.

The patterns I am trying to match all are bbcode style tags in a string.

for example: This is a paragraph of [blue]text[/blue] where all the words are of a [blue]color[/blue].

I need to replace each tag with a number and additional text as it occurs,
like [@@1@@] and [@@2@@]

I know I can match the pattern with preg_match('/[blue](.*?)[/blue]/i',$string)  or even replace preg_replace

But how can I get use either of those functions to get a count then replace the match with the it's count position?

Comment: "Count" confuses me, do you mean that you want to include an iterator into each replace?

For example, that `hello [blue]some[/blue] [blue]text[/blue]` becomes `hello [replaced_blue1]some[/replaced_blue1] [replaced_blue2]text[/replaced_blue2]` ?

Comment: I think that's hard to, if not impossible, with a regular regexp. If i were you, I'd check out the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag for [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get the position, and then split and splice the string according to it's matches. I'm busy until tomorrow, but I can give you a proof-of-concept then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $matches param.

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

if you pass `$matches` it will return an array with all the results. use `count($matches)` to return the count!

EDIT:
After you get the $matches array you can replace them using the array's key as the count value.

```
foreach($matches as $k=>$mat){
preg_replace ( /*same pattern*/,"[@@".$k."@@]", /* same subject */,1); //fourth param is to replace only one!
}
```

try this!

EDIT2: correct is preg_replace not preg_match (in my EDIT).

Comment: He wasn't asking about a count of the matches as a whole, but an incremental value to use in each replace.

Comment: My edit explains how to use the $matches like you need it, Blade.

Comment: thanks JDuarteDJ I didn't use your solution exactly because I have other things going on in my code but your solution did lead me to think differently and solve my problem. I can see however that your solution [edit 2] would work in the context I proposed. Unfortunately though I can't vote it up yet:( But thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Try preg_replace_callback:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\[blue\])([\[]*)(\[\/blue\])/i', function ($matches) {
    static $incr = 0;
    ++$incr;
    return '[@@'.$incr.'@@]'.$matches[2].'[@@'.$incr.'@@]';
}, $text);
```

see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for more info on that

Comment: interesting function, I didn't know about that one. Thanks for helping!